# How to convert picamera video frame to openCV object

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, camera, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to record a video with the python raspberry camera module and 
then convert each frame to a openCV frame with no success:

```
import time
import picamera
import cv2
import numpy as np

class BroadcastOutput(object):
    def __init__(self, camera):
        return


    def write(self, b):

        #create numpy array from b
        data = np.fromstring(b, dtype=np.uint8)

        #doesn't work with reshape either
        #data = np.fromstring(b, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(320, 280, 3)

        #enconde as image
        image = cv2.imdecode(data, 1)

        #test if is valid cv2 object -> fails
        cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)


    def flush(self):
        print('Waiting for background conversion process to exit')

    #camera setup and start
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.resolution = (320, 280)
        camera.framerate = 24
        time.sleep(2) # camera warm-up time

        print('Initializing broadcast thread')
        output = BroadcastOutput(camera)
        print('Starting recording')
        camera.start_recording(output, 'bgr')

        try:
            while True:
                camera.wait_recording(1)

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
        finally:
            print('Stopping recording')
            camera.stop_recording()
```

When i print my numpy array it has content, the image object after decode however is always none.

So my question: How do i correctly use the provided data in b as an cv2 frame? 
I'm still new to image processing...
Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: What's the point of obtaining `data` and `image` from `b`, when you then ignore them and use `b` in `cvtColor`? Actually, the `imdecode` seems a bit pointless two, considering you reshape the data into a 3 channel matrix. This whole snippet looks rather odd....

Comment: youare completely right... long day;) i tried to clarify my snipped and provided a complete and usable example

Comment: What's the length of `b` when `write` gets called? I'm not certain that it's guaranteed that you get one `write` per frame. The convenience wrappers provided in the library seem to do the conversion in `flush`. | If you look at the [`bytes_to_rgb` function](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.8/_modules/picamera/array.html), the `np.fromstring` approach seems to be in the right direction, assuming you've got the whole frame available.

Comment: You were right! the write callback doesn't receive a full frame!
@fireant provided the right hint with the PiRGBAnalysis class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See documentation of the [PiRGBAnalysis](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/api_array.html#picamera.array.PiRGBAnalysis) class.

Comment: As mentioned the write callback isn't receiving the full frame but PiRGBAnalysis is! So thanks for the hint, everything is working now.
Refer to http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32926/convert-the-frame-data-from-recording-into-a-numpy-array for a working example of the class

Comment: It's great you found a working sample code and shared the link here.